# Diffusion Equation with inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, heat-equation, reflection

How to solve:
\begin{cases}
u_t - ku_{xx} = 0 \hspace{2cm}  k>0, x>0, t>0 \\ u(x,0) = 0 \hspace{2.8cm}  x>0\\ u(0,t) = h(t) \hspace{3cm} t>0 
\end{cases}
I am trying to solve diffusion equation in two methods, Laplace transform and reflection method. I have solved it by Laplace transform. Here is the solution
$$
\int^{t}_{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt {4\pi k(t-s)^3}}xe^\frac{-x^2}{4k(t-s)} \quad dx
$$

I want to solve it by reflection method and make sure they are same. The following is the solution of reflection method.
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{t}_{0} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} [S(x-y, t-s) - S(x+y, t-s)] h(s)dsdy + h(t) \\
,where \hspace{1cm} S(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {4 \pi kt}}e^\frac{-x^2}{4kt}
$$

However, I can't simplify them. Any help in solving this is much appreciated!

Comment: Mathematica provides this solution, which agrees with the numerical solution: $$u(x,t) \to \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi  k}} \int_0^t \frac{h(s)}{(t-s)^\frac{3}{2}} exp(-\frac{x^2}{4k(t-s)}) ds $$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\mbox{With}\ k > 0,\ x >0\ \mbox{and}\ t>0;\quad
\left\vert\begin{array}{l}
\ds{\ \partiald{\on{u}\pars{x,t}}{t} - k\partiald[2]{\on{u}\pars{x,t}}{x} = 0}
\\[1mm]
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\on{u}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\\
\ds{\on{u}\pars{0,t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\on{h}\pars{t}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[3mm] \mbox{Lets}\  \ds{\hat{\on{u}}\pars{x,s} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\on{u}\pars{x,t}\expo{-st}\dd t}
\end{array}\right.$

I'll assume that $\ds{\underline{\lim_{x \to \infty}\on{u}\pars{x,t} = 0\ \mbox{and}\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\hat{\on{u}}\pars{x,s} = 0}}$.

---

\begin{align}
& \mbox{Therefore,}\
-\ \overbrace{\on{u}\pars{x,0}}^{\ds{0}}\ +\ s\hat{\on{u}}\pars{x,s} -
k\,\partiald[2]{\hat{\on{u}}\pars{x,s}}{x} = 0
\\ & \mbox{where}\ \hat{\on{u}}\pars{0,s} = \hat{\on{h}}\pars{s} \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{h}\pars{t}\expo{-st}\dd t.
\\ & \mbox{Then,}\ {\large \hat{\on{u}}\pars{x,s} = \hat{\on{h}}\pars{s}\expo{-\root{s/k}x}}.
\\[5mm] & \phantom{\ =\ }\mbox{Henceforth,}
\\ \color{#44f}{\large\on{u}\pars{x,t}} & = \int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
\hat{\on{h}}\pars{s}\expo{-\root{s/k}x}\expo{ts}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{h}\pars{\tau}\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
\expo{-\root{s/k}x}\expo{\pars{t - \tau}s}\ {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\dd\tau \\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{h}\pars{\tau}\bracks{t > \tau}\ \times
\\ & \bracks{%
-\int_{-\infty}^{0}
\expo{-\ic\root{-s/k}x}\expo{\pars{t - \tau}s}\ {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
\int_{0}^{-\infty}
\expo{\ic\root{-s/k}x}\expo{\pars{t - \tau}s}\ {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{t}\on{h}\pars{\tau}\ \times
\\ & \bracks{%
-\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\ic\root{s/k}x}\expo{-\pars{t - \tau}s}\ {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} +
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{\ic\root{s/k}x}\expo{-\pars{t - \tau}s}\ {\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{t}\on{h}\pars{\tau}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\sin\pars{\root{s \over k}x}\expo{-\tau s}\dd s}
^{\ds{{1 \over 2}\root{\pi \over k}x\ \tau^{-3/2}\,\exp\pars{-\,{x^{2} \over 4k\tau}}}}\dd\tau
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\large{x \over 2\root{\pi k}}\int_{0}^{t}{\expo{-x^{2}/\pars{4k\tau}} \over \tau^{3/2}}\on{h}\pars{\tau}\dd\tau}}
\\ &
\end{align}
A further reduction requires a  $\ds{particular\ \on{h}\pars{\tau}\ expression}$.